# Handle bad number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle11g

I have a query in a procedure that is returning 'ORA-01722: invalid number' for one record.  It is because the field is actually text and on one record someone has entered '.-11' instead of '-.11', and we are then trying to add that to another number.

When I know a bad number is possible, how do I handle the query?  I'd like to show a NULL or 'error' or something in the field, rather than skipping it (bad) or having the query fail (worse).

The query could be something like the following, with all fields defined as text:

```
SELECT Tbl_ID
     , Tbl_InValue
     , Tbl_OutValue
     , (Tbl_InValue + Tbl_OutValue)/2 Tbl_Avg
From MyTable
```

If I have table values like the following

```
Tbl_ID    Tbl_InValue    Tbl_OutValue
1          .5             3.2
2          1.1            .-11
3          -3             .5
```

I would like output something like

```
Tbl_ID    Tbl_InValue    Tbl_OutValue   Tbl_Avg
1          .5             3.2            1.85
2          1.1            .-11           ERROR
3          -3             .5             -1.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to perform the calculation and return a varchar2 result:

```
create function get_average(in_value in varchar2, out_value in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return to_char((to_number(in_value) + to_number(out_value)) / 2);
exception
  when others then
    return 'ERROR';
end;
```

Then use it in a select:

```
select get_average(Tbl_InValue, Tbl_OutValue) from MyTable;
```

Comment: also note this thread at asktom about plsql_optimize_level=3 issue for such functions: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7466996200346537833